# Updating text while zoomed changes font size

Tags: svg, d3.js

I've run into an issue with svg and d3.js in Chrome, not sure if it's a bug or how to work around it. The following jsfiddle shows the issue.

http://jsfiddle.net/9hzrckj7/

Zoom your browser (Chrome) in (<kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>+</kbd>) and click Run. You should see the text change from Text to Updated, and the size change depending on your zoom level.

html

```
<svg>
    <text x="100" y="100">
        Text
    </text>
</svg>
```

js

```
function update() {
    d3.select('text').text("Updated");
}

setInterval(function() {
    update();
}, 1000);
```

Below are images showing before and after, when zoomed in 250%

[image: Before]

[image: After]

Why is this happening? How can I stop it from happening or work around it?

Comment: Works for me. What exactly is the bug?

Comment: Which browser breaks? Could be a font cache issue on your PC?

Comment: @LarsKotthoff I have attached images showing what happens when zoomed in. Try zooming in to 200%+ to notice the change.

Comment: @AlvinK. Good point, I have this issue on Chrome on two different machines. I don't have this issue with Firefox or Internet Explorer 11.

Comment: @Craigy: Confirmed it is a chrome issue. Report to crbug.com

Comment: Reported bug to chromium: https://code.google.com/p/chromium/issues/detail?id=414707